# A mandatory parameter was not sent, was empty/null, or malformed. ( python-binance )

Tags: python, binance-api-client, pyalgotrade

I'm trying to open a 'long' position along with its stop loss and take profit orders.

The long position is successfully sent and placed. But whenever I try to create the TAKE_PROFIT order it throws an error

```
***binance.exceptions.BinanceAPIException: APIError(code=-1102): A mandatory parameter was not sent, was empty/null, or malformed.***
```

Code

```
position_order = client.futures_create_order(symbol='BTCUSDT', side='BUY', positionSide='BOTH', type=ORDER_TYPE_MARKET, quantity=0.05)
tp_order = client.futures_create_order(symbol='BTCUSDT', side='SELL', positionSide='BOTH', type='TAKE_PROFIT', quantity=0.05, stopPrice=26000.00, workingType='MARK_PRICE')
```

BINANCE CREATE NEW ORDER API DOCs
https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/futures/en/#new-order-trade

Comment: Looks like you're missing the price parameter. From the [docs](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/futures/en/#new-order-trade), if you scroll down: `Additional mandatory parameters based on type:` you'll see that TAKE_PROFIT requires `quantity`, `price` and `stopPrice`